# Convert a SQL Server CE edition database file (.sdf) to a sqlite3 supported database file

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce

I am looking for a way to support a existing SQL Server CE Database file (*.sdf) on a sqlite3.
Can someone  help me to find a way to Convert a SQL Server CE database file (.sdf) to a sqlite3 supported database file?
Does sqlite3 library provide any utility to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

You could export to a CSV file, then import that into SQLite. However, CSV files cannot represent all data types.

The tool at http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/ allows to export a database as an SQL script, which can then be executed directly in SQLite to recreate it there.

Comment: See my blog post here about issues relating to exporting to sqlite: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/08/exporting-sql-server-compact-to-sqlite.html

Comment: ErikEJ : Is it possible to avoid sql script conversion to move the sdf file to sqlite DB file ?

Comment: @PKHUN: SQL Server CE and SQLite speak slightly different SQL dialects; you have to use some tool that understands both.